# ConTeXt : TikZ foreach interaction with french module

Tags: tikz-pgf, context, french

The `\foreach` statement in TikZ is shifting the coordinates in my ConTeXt figures ; after some experimentation, I found it to be caused by the two instructions `\usemodule[french]` and `\setcharacterspacing[frenchpunctuation]`(any one of the instructions leads to the problem). Here is a MWE and the result :

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\starttext
\starttikzpicture[declare function={a=1; dth=90;}]
  \foreach \i in {0, 1, ..., 3} {
    \draw (\i*dth: a) ++ ({(\i-0.5)*dth}: a) coordinate (A-\i)
    arc ({(\i-0.5)*dth}: {(\i+0.5)*dth}: a) coordinate (B-\i);
  };
  \foreach \i/\j in {0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 3/0} {
    \draw [thin] (B-\i) -- (A-\j);
  }  
\stoptikzpicture

\usemodule[french]
\setcharacterspacing[frenchpunctuation]
\starttikzpicture[declare function={a=1; dth=90;}]
  \foreach \i in {0, 1, ..., 3} {
    \draw (\i*dth: a) ++ ({(\i-0.5)*dth}: a) coordinate (A-\i)
    arc ({(\i-0.5)*dth}: {(\i+0.5)*dth}: a) coordinate (B-\i);
  };
  \foreach \i/\j in {0/1, 1/2, 2/3, 3/0} {
    \draw [thin] (B-\i) -- (A-\j);
  }  
\stoptikzpicture
\stoptext
```

[image: the result]

A lot of troubles exist in the interaction between TikZ and french packages in LaTeX but I can't find anything about this behavior on the forums. I tried the `\shorthandoff` / `\shorthandon` pair that works in LaTeX, but ConTeXt raises a `Undefined Control Sequence` error. Is there a workaround for this problem ?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Does it work better if you remove the semicolon at the end of the first foreach loop? (Sorry, cannot test it here)

Comment: That... worked. I'm amazed at how simple this was in fact...

Comment: Another option is to add `\resetcharacterspacing` inside `\starttikzpicture`.

Comment: This solution seems more convenient in my opinion. Is there a fundamental reason to this behavior, in order to explain it in answer and close the subject ?

Comment: `\setcharacterspacing[frenchpunctuation]` adds a small space before high punctuation (;:!?) and quotes (« ») in French. `\resetcharacterspacing` stops this unwanted behaviour inside `\starttikzpicture`.

Comment: Just add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`.  I believe this has been asked and answered on this site but right now can't find a proper one...